# Buying stuff in Paris

Tags: buying-stuff

Any idea where to try and buy location sound stuff in Paris? Like mic capsules and hearphones?
Also portabraces.

Thanks¡

Answer (score 1):

In terms of buying gear, France is considerably more expensive than elsewhere. I live in Paris but always buy from either the UK or Germany. It usually works out cheaper to buy from abroad and pay a delivery charge than to buy from a French retailer. Don't forget that if you buy from a European seller, there are no issues with import tax. Buying from the US does mean import taxes are due. UK retailer Digital Village has a French website, even though it is essentially the UK store that you buy from. They also offer a price-match deal, so if you find what you're looking for cheaper elsewhere, they'll match it.

If you want to try before you buy, there are a number of companies in Paris that rent out audiovisual gear. But most of these will only stock different models of high-end gear - if you are interested in trying different models of headphones this becomes more difficult. I would advise doing extensive research on the Internet, then try and find a seller that allows you to try first. The same applies for Portabrace. The following links will help you on your way, I'll update with more links as I think of them:

[DC Audiovisuel (rental)](http://www.dcaudiovisuel.com/)

[Thomann (Germany)](http://www.thomann.de/fr/index.html)

[DV 247](http://www.dv247.fr/)

[Pinknoise Systems (UK)](http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/)

[Audio Fanzine (second hand gear)](http://fr.audiofanzine.com/petites-annonces/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tapages.fr/